# PHPUnit: Running tests from instances

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm wondering if there's a way to run a PHPUnit test from an object. Example

```php
<?php

class FooTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase{

   public function testTrue(){
     $this->assertTrue(true);
   }

}
```

Then in another PHP file:

```php
<?php

$test = new FooTest;

// function to run $test->testTrue();
```

Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible.  It can be done like this:

```
$test = new FooTest();
$results = $test->run();
```

When you create your tests, you are extending the PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase.  PHPUnit calls the `run` method on each of the tests.  So you would be able to call this yourself on the test to run it.  This method returns a PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult which you can use to see the results of the test.

Checkout the [PHPUnit source code](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit) for more info about the different objects.

Comment: Is there a way to run only specific tests?

Comment: Yes, for that I think that you will need to create a PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite and add the tests yourself.  https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/3.7/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php

Comment: Thanks. I figured as much. I guess I'll just extend a custom class so that I can implement the things I need to be done.